# I want to find all words using java regex, that starts with "#" and ends with space or "."

Tags: java, regex, string

This is a sample string

```
hi #myname, you  got #amount
```

I want to find all words using java regx, 
that starts with `#` and ends with space or `.` 
example `#myname`,`#amount`

I tried the following Regex, but it doesn't work.

```
String regx = "^#(\\s+)";
```

Comment: Please visit the [help] and read [ask].  You are expected to attempt the solution yourself and ask questions only after you have tried. Show us what you have tried.

Comment: i don't see any space or dot after amount

Comment: @AnoopLL - Try to be nicer, thanks.

Comment: thanks @cricket_007

Comment: Its ok @rock321987 as this is an example only with a case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one should be the way:

```
#(\w+)(?:[, .]|$)
```

- `#` matches `#` literally
- `\w` is a word with at least one letter
- `(?:)` is non-capturing group
- `[, .]|$` is set of ending characters including the end of line `$`

For more information check out [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/yC1dR3/1).

In Java don't forget to escape with double `\\`:

```
String str = "hi #myname, you  got #amount";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("#(\\w+)(?:[, .]|$)").matcher(str);
while (m.find()) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: what i used is "\\$(\\w+)" and this will serves my purpose.
thanks a lot man

Comment: Don't you mean `#` instead of `$`? Yes, it works, however it matches words with all the range of characters ending with.

Comment: oh sorry it is  "\\#(\\w+)

Answer (score 1):

```
String str = "hi #myname, you  got #amount";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\#(\\w+)").matcher(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the regex: `"(#\w*?[ .])"`

Comment: Yepp. Replacing `.*?` with `\w*?`