# My regex in replaceAll() in Java is not working

Tags: java, regex

I want to replace (words that starts with letter 'a' has one or more chars and ends with 'a')
with sign '!' and print it, but nothing is working. Why?

```
class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String s = "aba accca azzza wwwwa";
        System.out.println(s = s.replaceAll("\ba.+?a\b", "!"));
    }
}
```

Current ouput:
aba accca azzza wwwwa

Desired ouput:
! ! ! wwwwa

Comment: you mean this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37453828/i-want-to-find-all-words-using-java-regex-that-starts-with-and-ends-with-sp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The backslash inside replaceAll() should be escaped like below:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
               String s = "aba accca azzza wwwwa";
               s = s.replaceAll("\\ba.+?a\\b", "!");
               System.out.println(s);
    }
```

output: ! ! ! wwwwa